# Как сделать скриншот области экрана на js?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Мне нужно сделать снимок экрана по нажатию на кнопку.

Решение типа `html2canvas` не подойдёт (так как он опирается на DOM на сколько я знаю). Мне нужно решение похожее на работу плагинов, таких как `Lightshot`
Всё дело в том, что у меня на странице есть gif и если использовать обычный `html2cannvas`, то он отображает только первый кадр гифки, а не тот, который был сделан в момент нажатия клавиши.

Решение через `jsgif` мне тоже не подходит так как это занимает много времени, пока картинка прочитается покадрово

Куда мне копать что бы я смог делать снимок "поверх" страницы, опять же как подобные плагины для браузеров.
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: надо полагать, вы не про область экрана все таки, а про область html-страницы?

Comment: @teran, по факту да - это область html-страницы, но мне нужно заснять "поверх" как бы общую картину. Так как gif должна быть заснята в текущий момент. Вот что то такое я хочу получить http://prntscr.com/jl3deq на заднем фоне картинка с камеры, на переднем гифка. Мне нужно получить единый снимок

Comment: Дай пример кода с канвасом!
Никак не могу добиться хоть какого скрина...

Answer (score 1):

Если реализовывать как плагин для браузера, то вот этот https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab API расширения для chrome делает скриншот всей открытой вкладки. Выбрать нужную часть может сам человек, либо можно выполнить `executeScript` и получить нужные координаты.

Еще есть специальные сервисы, которые делают скриншот сайта, при необходимости можно использовать их. Минусы тут простые - несколько скриншотов в сутки и платно. Насчет нужного кадра не уверен.

Успехов.